Should we sum or mean reduce the KL loss in Bayes by Backprop?
I'm unsure if you're supposed to use sum or mean reduction of KL loss for Bayes by Backprop. For example, the BayesianTorch library does both: it reduces by mean across each individual tensor (as seen in kl_div() method), but then it sums across layers (as seen in get_kl_loss()). This is logically inconsistent of course and I suspect it's a bug. But I'm not sure which is correct and why. Could someone explain?
Also citations to related derivations would be appreciated.
